# How to differentiate between small and very small measure-zero sets?

Tags: measure-theory, vector-spaces

Suppose we take $\mathbb R^2$ with the standard sigma algebra as our measure space.

Then intuitively, there are two kinds of sets that both have a measure zero, but are different:

1. Sets of points: A set like $\{(0,0), (5,0)\}$, which only has points, which individually are also measure zero in the subspace $\{ (x,0) | x\in\mathbb R\}$.
2. Sets of lines: The subspace $\{ (x,0) | x\in[0,1] \}$, which is measure $1$ in the subspace $\{ (x,0) | x\in\mathbb R\}$.

**How do we formally distinguish between these very small measure zero sets and small measure zero sets?** note that I'm not sure what structure we need to introduce to talk about "subspace" here (maybe we need to assume a vector space structure).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Hausdorff dimension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausdorff_dimension) helps you to treat the first set as smaller than the second. The first set has Hausdorff dimension $0$ and the second one has Hausdorff dimension $1$.

Comment: Thanks! Can we also use this to see that the line segment $([0,1],0)$ is smaller than $([0,2],0)$, interpreted as subsets of $\mathbb R^2$? (Without using specifics about the measure space $\mathbb R^2$)

Comment: Hausdorff dimension does not distinguish between the two intervals but Hausdorff measure does.

Comment: Also Baire category and various porosity notions, various fractal measure zero notions (Hausdorff, Packing, Minkowski, etc.), various Borel measure zero notions, various capacity notions (and polar sets), Borel rarefraction notions, can be covered by countably many $C^1$ (or $C^2,$ etc.) curves, the huge number of various types of exceptional sets that arise in harmonic analysis, etc. Also, one can subdivide (many of) these into additional types by requiring that the closure of the set is small in the specified way. Not all of these distinguish between the specific sets mentioned, of course.